# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP]

Tags: php, .net, soap

I'm trying to handle an Api in PhP made with .Net and I user SoapClient to do it.

I can return the functions that it has like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

But when I'm trying to call a function with parameters it returns me the error:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message
>   because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the
>   expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'

I use this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_2','location'=>$urlWithoutWsdl, $params));

$response = $client->RegisterLoyaltyUser() ;
print_r($response);
```

So my question really is, do I have to call it with another way or with another library?

**EDIT**

The api is protected with username and password, maybe this is something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes surrounding SOAP 1_2. It's a constant not a string value